# c# Windows forms visual styles

Tags: c#

I am looking for something like visual themes for windows form application. I know i can change the visual style of components , thus i think there has to be some option to import like whole template to existing win forms application. Like CSS+html.

I have been searching for visual themes for c# for some time, and i cannot find anything. So i would like to ask if there is such option.

Not the `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`.  I mean something user-made.

Comment: There are, but only for WPF to my knowledge.

Comment: Are you talking about skinning your application if so see if there is anything [here](http://www.bing.com/search?q=skinning+forms+in+winforms&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=skinning+forms+in+winforms&sc=0-13&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=daba95a68f4047aab6e4a59b36dcd5e0) that will work

Comment: yes that might work, i just didn't know its called "skinning"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not a lot of options in this space outside of paid products.  Of the handful that I'm aware of the most complete options are likely:

- [DevExpress Skins](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/)
- [Telerik Visual Style Builder](http://www.telerik.com/winforms/visual-style-builder)